# Outreach activities in the COVID era

Tags: funding, united-states, education, covid-19, outreach

All the outreach activities planned this year for my project have been cancelled due to COVID-19 disruptions.
These include Summer math camp for high school students and seminar in local high schools.
These are stated in my grant proposal, and thus I have a responsibility to carry these out one way or another.
An easy way out is to replace everything with their Zoom version.
In my opinion and experience, however, the usefulness of such alternatives will be very limited.

What other outreach activities should we consider now?

Comment: I am also involved in outreach; I think a Zoom seminar could be quite well-received by overwhelmed teachers (at least they're overwhelmed and unsupported in the US, other countries are doing better, probs).

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim,  I have done a few of these, and I didn't like the experience.  Maybe I am just terrible at it.  With most students at home, it is very difficult to get them on Zoom in the first place.  When they are on Zoom, it is pretty obvious that they cannot focus.  In addition, many students actually do not have computers at home.  So we can use Zoom in if there is not other choices, but I'm trying to see if there's any other ideas we should consider.

Comment: Is weather in your locale amenable to outdoor seminars with social distancing?

Comment: Great point!  Will investigate.

Comment: I suspect that your grant agency may be aware of the pandemic and public health limits put on such activities this summer.

Comment: What do you mean by "responsibility"? Do you mean to yourself (ie a moral one) or to the grant givers?

Comment: @JonCuster, Agreed.  In the worse case, if nothing can be done, I'm sure grant agency will understand.  But in US at least, things are not getting better.  Actually it's getting worse quickly.  I don't see how we can get back to normal quickly.  It could be years until we get back to normal.  It certainly feels wrong to do nothing at all for two years, three years...

Comment: @user111388, I don't think the grant agency will hold me legally responsible.  But a promise is a promise.

Comment: @ssquidd - oh, for sure. On a major project I'm working, we have decided to replan based on not being 'normal' for at least the next 15 months, and that the plan after than may need to be drastically adjusted as well - this is on a $1B class project. On the other hand, this also means you could take some time and try various experiments. The options are not good, though - it is pretty much either something online or something in person with only a few people (and could get cancelled rapidly). Right now there are no good options.

Answer (score 1):

- The most responsible course of action is to postpone your in-person outreach until it is safe to conduct it.  In-person outreach is very effective.  Get the funding agency's approval.
- An alternative is to create asynchronous outreach content.  This is less effective, but can reach a wider audience.  For example, you can record YouTube videos of activities.  Disadvantages include difficulty getting your intended audience to watch the video.  Advantages over Zoom/synchronous include no need to schedule or register people, and the potential to do things over when they don't work.
- Some people are running online competitions, but I don't know yet if they work.